# Split view possibly causing iPad to not reload tableview data, works on iPhone

Tags: swift, firebase

I am testing my app on my iPhone and iPad and I noticed that on the iPhone and iPhone simulator my `tableView` perfectly reflects what is on my Firebase database. However, on the iPad my tableview shows old data. I tested this by adding data to `Firebase` in various ways and when I recalled the method that fetches the data the iPhone updates the tableview while the iPad does not.

I am using a `UISplitView`, and I have put breakpoints and they are being hit. So the method that fetches from Firebase is being called the iPad is just not updating the tableview.

I am stumped as to why this is happening.

I have tried calling the following method from `ViewWillAppear` and `ViewDidAppear` and it gets called each time. I also put a breakpoint on the line `self.tableView.reloadData()`

```
  func getServices() {
if let theCard = card {
  FirebaseUtility.shared.getServicesFor(card: theCard, completion: { (services, error) in
    if let theServices = services {

      self.serviceArray.removeAll()
      self.serviceArray = theServices
      self.getCategories()
      self.sortArray()

      self.tableView.reloadData()
    } else {
      if let theError = error?.localizedDescription {
        let errorMessage = theError
        print(errorMessage)
      }
    }
  })
} else {
  navigationController?.popViewController(animated: true)
 }
}
```

The FirebaseUtility.shared.getServices method is

```
  func getServicesFor(card: Card, completion: @escaping (_ services: [Service]?, _ error: Error?) -> Void) {
let servicesRef = ref.child(FirebaseKeys.newServices).child(card.cardID)
    servicesRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: { (snapshot) in // was screwing up on ipad

  let enumerator = snapshot.children
  var serviceArray = [Service]()
  while let serviceSnapshot = enumerator.nextObject() as? DataSnapshot {

    if let serviceDict = serviceSnapshot.value as? [String : Any] {
      let service = Service(id:serviceSnapshot.key, cardId: card.cardID, serviceDict: serviceDict)
      serviceArray.append(service)
    }
  }
  completion(serviceArray, nil)
})
}
```

I have also tried clearing the array and refreshing the tableview so I know that it is empty and then setting a delay func on the func that pulls the firebase data. The data on the iPhone is still different than the iPad.

Edit: Instead of observeSingleEvent I changed the Firebase call to observe so now the issue is solved, however I am still curious as to why observeSingleEvent was having issue on iPad vs iPhone

Comment: What if you dispatch your `reloadData()` to the main queue?

Comment: @PhillipMills No change in behavior

Comment: Just to isolate the issue, would it be possible for you to try on the iPad with a simple `UITableViewController` instead of `UISplitViewController` ?

Comment: is this issue is from `firebase` side?? check which data you getting from firebase(print (snapshot.result))